# What is a position of [software-developer]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

We're getting rather steady stream of blatantly off-topic questions in [software-developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-developer) tag.

A few recent examples:

- <s>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338512/hired-as-developer-and-thrown-into-support-after-1-month</s>
- <s>https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337736/is-it-better-to-focus-on-mastering-one-language-framework-or-just-learn-multiple</s>
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337494/confused-about-software-engineering-career
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336838/understanding-software
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336733/need-career-advice
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336038/job-ad-senior-frontend-developer-in-berlin-startup-company

10K users can follow the links to see how bad these are and for those who can't see deleted questions, first five are outright [career / education advice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/) and the last one is a spammy job ad.

As of now this tag has 37 closed and 10 open questions and a handful [historically locked ones](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-developer%5D+locked%3Ayes).

I haven't yet seen on-topic questions where this tag was useful which makes me wonder could we maybe burninate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already removed the tag from the historically locked questions.

I do ask that people take a few minutes before casting delete votes on closed questions, especially questions that are marked duplicates. For example, [this recently closed question had a net score of -3 and 2 delete votes, but was already closed as a duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257240/question-about-requirements). This question was rightfully closed as a duplicate, but was a well-written question with a well-written answer. It's a useful sign post to the question/answer set that it is a duplicate of. This question should be edited to remove the bad tag (and to do any other cleanup of questions and answers), but still has value as a duplicate.

When editing, you are bumping a question to the homepage. Please try to look at the title, body, and answers to see if any edits are necessary. Of course, please flag anything you can't do on your own for moderator attention.

Answer (score 9):

[software-developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-developer) is a blatant [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/); everyone on this site should already be a software developer, so the tag does not add anything.  If you see it, feel free to edit, vote to close and/or cast a delete vote as appropriate, and then remove the tag.